# extract data from nested loop

Tags: python, json

I have a scenario where I am extracting data from a [json](https://jsfiddle.net/zohkpyLd/1/) response in this below conditions :

I am Looping through the json and finding value of `active` if `active` `true` then under the same parent array find under `cls` `type` if `type` is `alpha1` return the `eces` value (in this case 260551).
if after looping through json there is no value of `active` as `true` or value of active is `true` but in that same parent array under `cls` type is not `alpha1` then return not found.

Here I am getting the value of `eces` correctly but how can I get the value of the this fields as well `address`, `c_m`, `active`, `type` then construct a key value mapping of all the extracted data and save in a json file.

here is what I have tried :

```
    found = False
    for di in d:
        if di.get('active', False):
            for cl in di.get('cls', []):
                if cl.get('type') == 'alpha1':
                    print(di['eces'])
                    found = True

    if not found:
        print("Not found")
```

desired json output :

> ```
> {
>     "res1": [{
>         "eces": "260551",
>         "res2": [{
>             "c_m": 345,
>             "clsfrmt": [
>                 {
>                     "address": "{\"I_G\":\"CD\",\"I_D\":\"01\",\"I_Y\":\"C1\",\"I_XD\":\"04\",\"I_TY\":1,\"S_L\":\"https://testappsampler.com\",\"O_DC\":\"\"}",
>                     "type": "Alpha"
>                 }
>             ],
>             "active": true
>         }]
>     }]
> }
> ```

I am stuck in creating the json data in this structure , any help would be great.

Comment: I would add a breakpoint at the desired line and see what your local variables are showing.

Comment: @scottsaenz where should I add the breakpoints ? very sorry but I dont know how to proceed here in order to get the value of those mentioned keys

Comment: I would add it at both if statements inside your for loop. If you are unsure of how to use breakpoints, you can pickle the d object and inspect it in isolation.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Comment: @AMC issue is I dont know how to proceed further if I want to have a json structured response like the one mentioned in `desired json output`

Answer (score 0):

While I'd advice to refactor this code in some proper way, this will create a mapping in very straight maner:

```
import json

dump = []
for di in d:
    if di.get('active', False):
        for cl in di.get('cls', []):
            if cl.get('type') == 'alpha1':
                dump.append(
                {
                    "res1": [{
                        "eces": di['eces'],
                        "res2": [{
                            "c_m": di['c_m'],
                            "clsfrmt": [
                                {
                                    "address": di['cls'][0]['address'],
                                    "type": di['cls'][0]['type']
                                }
                            ],
                            "active": di['active']
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            )

s = json.dumps(dump) # this is your JSON string
```

[Result](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a6897b5dc9754cbc96c7310e23cf9aaf).

Comment: the response you are appending is not the one that I have posted in the question, basically I am finding it difficult to have a json structure as output as I have mentioned in `desired json output`

Comment: Changed answer - check the structure now.

Comment: I am using for loop here so there are many item that I am iterating the place where you have mentioned `di['cls'][0]['address']` will that `[0]` be fixed or shall I replace it with any key value that is used to iterate ?

Comment: @Thomas it depends on your data structure. If you are iterating though a list of mappings like the one you showed in example, then this should be fine, still needs to be checked by you. In the example you showed `cls` key is a list of nested mappings. Without knowing whole data you operate with, it's hard to say if `address` is always at the zero index - you need to find out this yourself.

Comment: code gives syntax error at  this line `dump.append(`